# How to convert date/time data in pandas to DATE data in DolphinDB?

Tags: python, pandas, dolphindb

In Python API, what format and type should the date/time data in pandas be so that it can be automatically recognized as DATE instead of NANOTIMESTAMP when being uploaded to DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script like `df.time.astype("datetime64[D]")` to convert date/time data in pandas to np.datetime64[D], which will be automatically converted to DATE data in DolphinDB through Python API.